# How to count number of classes generated using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following HTML code.

Here 2 add/remove link exists. **1)** Add More Details(+) **2)** Add(+)

when I click on **Add(+)** link its `clone` the `tour_wrap` class div and counting the number of `trip_counting` class div cloned/added. **Like:** Trip 1, Tip 2, Trip 3 etc..

And, I have another link called **Add More Details (+)** which is clone the `tour_wrap` div.

So when I click on this link twice for e.g then it's clone the `tour_wrap` div 2 times, That's good.

Now I have 3 `tour_wrap` div. In this div's you can see that I have the link **Add(+)** 3 times, right? Yes. So when  I click on any **Add(+)** link then it's counting the Total number of `trip_counting` classes added But I want to count only corresponding `trip_counting` classes.

**Check this image:**

[image]

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="tour_wrap">
   <!-- some other html code for the tour -->
   <div class="trip_wrap">  
      <h5 class="badge badge-success trip_counting">Trip 1</h5>    
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>From</label>
            <input type="text" name="ow_from[]" class="form-control" placeholder="From">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>To</label>
            <input type="text" name="to[]" class="form-control" placeholder="To">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="change_trip text-right">
            <a class="btn add_button_trip trip_btn">Add(+)</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div> <!-- end trip_wrap -->
</div> <!-- end tour wrap -->
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group change text-right">
         <a class="btn add_button add_more add_more_btn"><strong>Add More Details (+)</strong></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div> <!-- end row -->
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
// for all way
$("body").on("click",".add_button",function(){
  var html = $(".tour_wrap").first().clone();
  $(html).find(".change").html("<a class='btn remove remove_more'>Remove Details(-)</a>");
  $(".tour_wrap").last().after(html);

  $('.counting').each(function(i, elm) {
      $(elm).text('Detail ' + (i + 1));
  });
});

$("body").on("click",".remove",function(){
   $(this).parents(".tour_wrap").remove();
});

// add more trip
$("body").on("click",".add_button_trip",function(){
  var html = $(".trip_wrap").first().clone();
  $(html).find(".change_trip").html("<a class='btn remove_trip remove_more trip_btn_remove'>Delete(-)</a>");
  //$(".trip_wrap").last().after(html);
  $('.trip_wrap').each(function(i, elm) {
     $(elm).last().after(html);
  });

  $('.trip_counting').each(function(i, elm) {
     $(elm).text('Trip ' + (i + 1));
  });
});

$("body").on("click",".remove_trip",function(){
  $(this).parents(".trip_wrap").remove();
});
```

Comment: why don't you count `trip_counting` classes from the current `tour_wrap` parent only?

Comment: If you would use an object or array as a data store instead of the HTML, this would be a simple `x.length`.

Comment: @ManishYadav what should I  do then?

Comment: you can get the current `tour_wrap ` parent then using that as a parent selector count the number of `trip_counting` classes in it. This will give you a correct count according to current parent.

Comment: Great! could you show me an example code Manish ?

Comment: Can you make a minimalistic jsfiddle of your code? I can modify it for you.

Comment: Please check my all jQery code I have posted.

Comment: `$('.tour_wrap').each(function(k,v){
 $(this).find('.trip_counting').each(function(i, elm) {
  $(elm).text('Trip ' + (i + 1));
  });
});` try this.

Comment: where should I add this code?

Comment: instead of this `$('.trip_counting').each(function(i, elm) {
     $(elm).text('Trip ' + (i + 1));
  });` use my code

Comment: well, counting is good now but if i click on `Add(+)` link on first `tour_wrap` div then  new filed is generated to the bottom of second `tour_wrap`. it's should generate bellow the corresponsding `tour_wrap`.

Comment: replace `$('.trip_wrap').each(function(i, elm) {
     $(elm).last().after(html);
  });` with `$(this).parents('.trip_wrap').append(html);`

Comment: well, that solved but now new div is copied 3 times 6 times instead of 1 time after click on the Add(+) link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177490/discussion-between-manish-yadav-and-creativeartbd).

Comment: @ManishYadav Did you check my given link?

Comment: I did, but according to me most of your logic is wrong.. for an instance, when removing a trip then the trip numbers don't auto arrange themselves in order, and many other mistakes like this. I would suggest that you start working again for this particular functionality. It will require a lot of effort in rectifying all the mistakes